# No suitable HttpMessageConverter found when converting JSON response?

Tags: java, json, spring, rest

I'm getting a simple `json` response and wanted to map it as follows to a pojo:

```
ResponseEntity<JsonEntity> response = new RestTemplate().getForEntity(url, JsonEntity.class);

@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class JsonEntity {
    //@JsonProperty getter + setter...
}
```

But I'm just getting the following exception. What might be missing?

> org.springframework.web.client.RestClientException: Could not extract
>   response: no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for response type
>   [class JsonEntity] and content type [application/octet-stream]

Answer (score 0):

For the default JSON `HttpMessageConverter`, you'll need to add either Jackson 1 or Jackson 2 to your classpath.

Otherwise, you can add some other JSON library and write your own `HttpMessageConverter` which can do the deserialization.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out the service did not repond with `UTF-8` encoding, but `ISO 8859-1`, which caused the error as Jackson parser can only handly utf-8.